# Is it important to `memoize` with Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

After reading a barrage of articles on React, Redux and memoization, I'll like to ask a question... Can I get away with this use case:

Assume I have a redux store with the following data

```
// reduxStore
module.exports = {
    randomData: [
        { name: 'John', age: 30 },
        { name: 'Peter', age: 25 },
        { name: 'Brenda', age: 15 }
    ];
};
```

Now, in my component, I will like to retrieve the average age. I go about it like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export function TestComponent(props) {
    return <p>The sum of ages is: {props.ageSum}</p>;
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    ageSum: state.randomData.map(datum => datum.age).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr)
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TestComponent);
```

I'm under the impression that this works the same as the examples given with `reselect` and the other libraries recommended by React.

Can someone please explain, if and why this example is not wise when it comes to optimization...

Comment: Unless `state.randomData` changes, the component will not be re-rendered, if it does change the calculation has to be redone so no point in using memoization anyways

Answer (score 2):

That example would *work*, but it would not be best for performance.

In most cases, calling `map()` in your `mapStateToProps` function will result in a new array reference being returned.  Different references means the results are not shallow equal to last time, so your component will re-render.  Memoization can help ensure that you only generate new references (like `someArray.map()`) when the input values have actually changed.

In your case, the `map` result is immediately being fed into a `reduce()`, and used to calculate a sum.  Assuming the calculated sum is the same each time, your component will not re-render, so it's not as much of a concern.

However, it's likely that `state.randomData` has not changed most of the time, in which case the `map().reduce()` is doing unnecessary work.  Memoization would also help avoid that.

See the [React-Redux docs on writing `mapState` functions](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate) and my post [Idiomatic Redux: Using Reselect Selectors for Encapsulation and Performance](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/12/idiomatic-redux-using-reselect-selectors/) for more details on this.

Comment: So, can you clarify with an extra case where the `name` values in each `randomData` element? If I understand clearly, it means memoization will not re-render whent the `name` value changes, but will re-render when the `age` changes

Comment: Updating data immutably means making copies of all the affected values and modifying those. If I wanted to change "Peter" to "Fred", I would need to copy and modify the object at `state.randomData[1]`, the array at `state.randomData`, and the object at `state`. Those would all produce new object/array references. Ideally, your `mapState` function would only recalculate sums if `state.randomData` is a new array reference (which indicates some of its contents have changed).

Comment: I have a feeling this example doesn't really bring out the best between my approach and memoization. Can you please offer one that better clarifies it @markerikson? Thanks

Comment: Flipping the request around: can you clarify what the actual question is? :)